# Get presence returns forbidden. Set presence works fine

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I've hit a weird situation where my graphclient has permissions to set presence for a user, but aren't allowed to read presence from the same user.

I have read/readwrite permissions added in the Azure portal, for the app registration.

There's no further explanation in the error:

```
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"","innerError":{"request-id":"ddc6fc84-0edc-4fc9-b606-3c0de6d6067c","date":"2023-07-03T06:34:02","client-request-id":"ddc6fc84-0edc-4fc9-b606-3c0de6d6067c"}}}
```

And I attempt to read presence like so:

```
var presence = await graphClient.Users[userId].Presence.Request().GetAsync();
```

When I set presence it works, and I do that like so:

```
await graphClient.Users[userId].Presence
.SetPresence(availability, activity, _clientDetails.ClientId, new Duration("PT1H")).Request()
.PostAsync();
```

Here are my permissions:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious, or have anyone else experienced similar issues?

Comment: We checked this at our end in graph explorer by giving only Presence.Read.All. It worked fine. Seems like an issue with C# SDK, we will check and get back to you. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDRIZ.png

Comment: Can you please also add Presence.Read as delegated permission and check again.

Comment: Presence.read.all is already a delegate permission.

Comment: Apologies for the delay we tried to check the logs but couldn't find anything. We will check internally and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Engineering team has looked into logs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXOPK.png. Could you please refresh access token for MsGraph API and try again. Presence.Read.All should be enough to get presence of other users. If you are still facing the issue could you please share new request id and time range so that team can investigate further.

Comment: Could you please share new request id and time range so that team can investigate further.

Comment: IT seems that the Presence.Read.All permission is only enough when it's delegated, as answered here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1323478/get-presence-returns-forbiddne-set-presence-works 
It seems misleading to even have the permission as application type, but it does work when i use a refreshtoken generated by admin login. 
This dodesn't solve the need to read presence from my application, but confirms that it works as delegate.

Comment: It seems that it is not intended to work with application permissions, even though there is a  Presence.Read.All applicaation permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that reading presence is not intended to work when using application permissions.
Which makes the Presence.Read.All application permission a bit misleading.

Answered here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1323478/get-presence-returns-forbiddne-set-presence-works
And confirmed that the code from my question works when i generate a token by logging in, instead of creating it using the tenant Id.

Hopefully this answer can be replaced sometime, when it is possible to read presence using the application permission, but for now that's not the case.

Comment: I can confirm, that this is still an issue in November 2023.
I figured out there is a workaround, which is somehow dirty but does its job: You have to have a users consent as described above in your tenant, BUT you need only one constent. So you can create let's say a "service account", let this service account consent once and use a long lived token (`offline_access`), now you can switch between users on the server/application side: Use the token of the service account to read a status of any user and the application account to set the status.